# Codename One: App broken after iOS build

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone

I have been building my App for Android repeatedly without any errors. I know tried to also build it for iOS which would not work, since I now know that I need a Mac.

After that, I tried to build it again for Android and now everything seems broken. IntelliJ tells me everywhere that it "can't resolve Symbols" and "can't resolve methods". I tried opening and closing the IDE and also restarted the computer, tho I am not able to make a successful build again. This just started after the failed iOS build.

Here is a Screenshot for you, those are very simple lines, there is no reason for them not to work. I am really clueless right now what wrong.

[image]

Maybe someone of you has an advice for me? I can only repeat, i did not change the code at all, but it just won't compile anymore, neither in the simulator nor with the Android build.

Comment: As @Carlos Verdier mentioned, Mac is only needed to submit your apps to store. Codename One is capable of all iOS development process without a Mac.

Comment: FYI this might have happened because sending a build updates the libraries if there is a new version. This is a problem that occasionally happens on NetBeans where the AST cache gets corrupted. It's solvable in NetBeans by removing the caches, not sure how that's done in intellij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may be due to a missing or corrupt **CodenameOne_SRC.zip** and/or **CodenameOne.zip** and/or **JavaSE.jar** files.

Solution:

Create a new dummy Codename One project, right click on the dummy project and select `Properties` then click the `Update Project libs` button. Once it's done, close the dialog and right click the project again, then navigate to `Codename One` -> `Refresh cn1lib files`.

Now close the dummy project and minimize your IDE and go open your Dummy project folder in your file explorer. Now copy the **CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar** and **JavaSE.jar** found in the main folder to the relative path of your faulty project, replace them if already exist. Do the same for **CLDC11.jar**, **CodenameOne.jar**, **CodenameOne_SRC.zip** that are found in the lib folder of your dummy project.

Go back to IntelliJ and right click on your faulty project and navigate to `Codename One` -> `Refresh cn1lib files`, then clean and build your project.

This should fix any reference or missing class issues.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you don't need a Mac to build an iOS project in Codename One.